# How to debug a Tree Summing and Runtime error?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am looking at [problem 112](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=48) from UVa Online Judge.

For a couple of weeks ago, I got some homeworks from my university and the thing is that, though other problems are accepted on the UVa, I cannot figure out what is going wrong with this problem. I've already run the input from [Udebug website](https://www.udebug.com/UVa/112) and there was no problem. I double-checked the result and now, I'm sick and tired of solving this issue.

Here are details about what has happened. First of all, I increase the BUFSIZE to 2^20 in order to avoid any memory overflow. The result? Failed. Second, I downsized the size of the element in the stack I made. The result? Failed. Lastly, I removed an eol character of the result just in case. The result? Failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 16384

typedef struct node {
    int element[BUFSIZE];
    int size;
    int current;
}Stack;//This is a stack I made

static Stack *stack;
static int level;//This is a level of a node in the whole tree
static int integer;//This is an integer that should be came out from the sum() function

bool initialize(void) {
    if (stack == NULL)
        stack = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    stack->size = BUFSIZE;
    stack->current = 0;
    return true;
}

bool push(int number) {
    if (stack == NULL)
        return false;
    if ((stack->current + 1) > stack->size)
        return false;

    stack->element[stack->current] = number;
    stack->current++;
    return true;
}

int pop() {
    if (stack->current <= 0)
        return 0xFFFFFFFF;
    stack->current--;
    return stack->element[stack->current];
}

int sum() {
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    if (stack == NULL)
        return 0xFFFFFFFF;
    if (stack->current == 0)
        return 0xFFFFFFFF;

    for (i = 0; i < stack->current; i++)
        result += stack->element[i];

    return result;
}//Sum all the values in the stack and return it.

void replace(char * o_string, char * s_string, char * r_string) {
    char *buffer = (char *)calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
    char * ch;

    if (!(ch = strstr(o_string, s_string)))
        return;
    strncpy(buffer, o_string, ch - o_string);
    buffer[ch - o_string] = 0;
    sprintf(buffer + (ch - o_string), "%s%s", r_string, ch + strlen(s_string));
    o_string[0] = 0;
    strcpy(o_string, buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return replace(o_string, s_string, r_string);
}//This is a function I found on Google. Memory usage optimization is not guaranteed.


int main(void) {
    char *buffer;
    char *line;
    char *restOfTheString;
    char *token;
    bool checked = false, found = false;

    int i = 0, j = 0, scannedInteger, result = 0, array[4096];

    buffer = (char *)calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
    restOfTheString = (char *)calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
    line = (char *)calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
    for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
        array[i] = -1;
    }
    level = 0;
    integer = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {//Get input line by line
        if (line[0] != '\n') {
            token = strtok(line, "\n");
            if (strlen(line) >= 1) {
                strcat(buffer, token);
            }
        }   
    }

    replace(buffer, " ", "");
    replace(buffer, "()()", "K");

    strcpy(restOfTheString, buffer);
    i = 0;
    while (restOfTheString[i] != 0) {
        if (level == 0 && !checked) {//If the level of the node is 0, then it is clearly the summed value I need to find out on the whole tree.
            initialize();
            sscanf(&restOfTheString[i], "%d%s", &integer, &restOfTheString[0]);
            i = -1;
            checked = true;
        }

        if (restOfTheString[i] == '(') {
            checked = false;
            level++;
        }//If there is an openning bracket, then increase the level of the node.
        else if (restOfTheString[i] == ')') {
            if (restOfTheString[i - 1] != '(')
                if (pop() == 0xFFFFFFFF)
                    return 0;
            level--;
            if (!found && level == 0) {
                array[j] = 0;
                j++;
                free(stack);
                stack = NULL;
            }//If there is a closing bracket, then it's time to check whether the level of the node is 0. If the level of the node is 0, then we need to report the result to the 'array' which is an integer array and move on to the next input.
            else if (found && level == 0) {
                array[j] = 1;
                j++;
                free(stack);
                stack = NULL;
                found = false;
            }
        }
        else if (restOfTheString[i] == '-' && !checked) {
            if (sscanf(&restOfTheString[i], "%d%s", &scannedInteger, &restOfTheString[0]) == 2) {
                if (push(scannedInteger) == false)
                    return 0;
                i = -1;
            }
        }//If there is a minus character, then it's obvious that the next couple of characters are a negative integer and I need to scan it out of the whole input.
        else if (restOfTheString[i] >= 48 && restOfTheString[i] <= 57 && !checked) {
            if (sscanf(&restOfTheString[i], "%d%s", &scannedInteger, &restOfTheString[0]) == 2) {
                if (push(scannedInteger) == false)
                    return 0;
                i = -1;
            }
        }//If there is a numerous character, then it's obvious that the next couple of characters are a negative integer and I need to scan it out of the whole input.

        else if (restOfTheString[i] == 'K') {
            if ((result = sum()) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
                return 0;
            if (result == integer) {
                found = true;
            }
        }//The 'K' character means the integer scanned prior to this iteration is a value in a leaf. So I need to call the sum() function in order to figure it out the result.
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (array[i] != -1) {
        if (array[i] == 1)
            printf("yes\n");
        else if (array[i] == 0)
            printf("no\n");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though it is clearly suspicious about the memory usage, I don't know how to track the stack on my system.

Comment: For a lot of memory related issues Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks mate, I owe you one. And can you do me another favor? The valgrind program says there is a memory leak on calloc'd memory space such as buffer, line, restOfTheString on main function and buffer on replace() function. Can you see where the memory leak happens?

Comment: Sry, but I am under real pressure to finish relaxing, because weekend is ending soon. ;-) ... - If I were you I'd try to debug my code using a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about valgrind, alk and have a good weekend!

Comment: You allocate storage for these strings at the beginning of `main`, but don't `free` the memory before leaving `main`. That's a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use many questionable practices.

- You free and re-allocate the stack from scratch. The stack has a fixed size in your case; allocate one at the beginning of main and free once at the end.
- You set the index `i` to −1 as indicator, but keep on accessing `restOfString[i]` later. `restOfString` is an allocated string and writing to bytes before the actual data might corrupt the internal information that thze system keeps for allocated memory. This might lead to errors when freeing. In any case, it's undefined behaviour.
- You read the input line-wise and concatenate everything into one huge string. You use `strcat` for this, which will get slower as your string grows. If you must load everything into a large buffer, consider using `fread`.
- Your recursive `replace` method also does a lot of copying of temporarily allocated buffers.
- This:

  ```
  sscanf(&rest[i], "%d%s", &integer, &rest[0]);
  ```

  looks fishy. You store the result in the string that you are reading, albeit at different indices. Result and source may overlap, which probably is undefined behaviour. In any case, it entails a lot of copying. Instead of using `sscanf`, you could read the integer with `strtol`, which gives you the position of the string after parsing the number. Continue scanning the old string at the resulting offset.

Your problems seem to be not in the core algorithm but with reading the input. Ihe [assignment](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=48) does not mention a maximum line length. This may be a sign that you shouldn't read the input in a line context.

You can use the `scanf` functions which don't know about line breaks. You can make use of the fact that unsuccessful scanning with data conversion, e.g. scanning an integer, resets the input stream.

Such a strategy would require only storage for the current token. You don't even need a stack if you use recursion. I doubt that the test cases in the online judge will break the stack limit, even if there they contain degenerate trees with a large depths.

Comment: This should be useful although it doesn't solve my problem. But thanks for letting me know what is wrong with my code!